# how many $0$ does $150!$ have when it transform to base $7$?

Tags: number-theory

how many $0$ does $150!$ have when it transform to base $7$?

---

can someone help me please how can I able to solve this problem.thanks for your help.

Comment: What does it mean for a number to "have" some number of $0$s?

Comment: @sumo: Do you mean trailing zeros or total number of zeros?

Comment: total number of zeros

Comment: and also it has to convert in base 7 , calculation should not be in decimal numbers .

Comment: But what is the motivation for this question? Where does it come from? Trailing 0s seems perfectly natural but all, this is a bit puzzling for me.

Comment: See Legendre's result in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Number_theory.

Comment: find total power of 7 in 150! using legendre's equality mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

$150!$ has [$311$ digits in base $7$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=150!%20in%20base%207), and if I counted correctly $62$ of them are $0$'s.

As a not very surprising side note, $150!$ has [$2$ digits in base $150!$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=150!%20in%20base%20150!), and $1$ of them is a $0$.

Answer (score 0):

lets assume number 7 in base 10. when this converted to base 7 then number becomes 10. here number of zeores at the end of number when converted to base 7 is 1. nuber of 7's in 7 is 1.

Similarly consider number 49 in base 10. when we convert this number to base 7 number becomes 100. here number of zeores at the end of number when converted to base 7 is 2. number of 7's in 49 is 2.

SO for the question at the hand we need to find out number of 7's in 150!.

so number of 7's in 150 ! are as follows

150/7+ 150/49

=21+3= 24 (take integral part only)

so number of zeros will be 24.

Comment: But OP asked for the total number of zeros, not the trailing ones.