# 2015! to base 6... How many zeros does it have?

Tags: factorial

I'm trying to resolve this problem:
"How many trailing zeros does $(2015!)_6$ have?"

I checked this discussion ([how many $0$ does $150!$ have when it transform to base $7$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455673/how-many-0-does-150-have-when-it-transform-to-base-7)) and I followed the same reasoning. I counted $969$ trailing zeros assuming that whenever a $2 *3$ factor appears, it adds a trailing zero (the same that happens with $2*5$ in decimal system).But other people counted different values.

Can you please check the result? thanks

Comment: You cannot use the *exact same* reasoning, because $7$ is prime and $6$ is not (in fact, the number you've got is too small). You can, however, do the same thing for $2$ and $3$ and choose the one with the least exponent (spoiler: it will always be the one of $3$).

Comment: Yes i didn't divided for 7. I did the same calculations written by 
Hagen von Eitzen but i probably made a mistake with sum or fractions :)

Answer (score 2):

$2015!$ is divisible by $2^a3^b$ where
$$ a=\left\lfloor\frac{2015}2\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{2015}4\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{2015}8\right\rfloor+\ldots =1007+503+251+\ldots=2005 $$
and 
$$ b=\left\lfloor\frac{2015}3\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{2015}9\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{2015}{27}\right\rfloor+\ldots =671+223+74+\ldots=1002 $$
and neither $a$ nor $b$ can be increased.
It follows that $2015$ is divisible by $(2\cdot3)^{1003}$ and no more.

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake during the second fractions. Besides i think i made a very silly step... I first changed 2015! to base 6... then i performed calculations in base 6 (terribly annoying), i obtained $671$ from the first operation but then things became too confuse.